# Memory Efficient Abstract Linear data type to store and iterate 1 million to 2 million records in java - Apache camel

Tags: java, memory, apache-camel, jsch

This is a curiosity question, recently we faced out of memory issue with one of our microservices. This memory issue happens once in a month so basically application is running for 1 month without any issue but after that it is throwing out of memory. Our guess memory is increasing after running through daily files and storing them into DB which not getting cleared by GC somehow.

We tried to refactor the code wherein I suggested to use custom array list (standard size) or singly linked list to store them. This made me wonder whether we have any memory efficient dynamic list to store large volume of custom objects.

Note: the list just need to store the record and access them in FIFO order, once recorded into DB it will be cleared

Note 2: please share if you know any memory efficient ADT already available in Apache commons collection or anything as such.

Comment: This sounds like a memory leak and not something that is solved by using a different data structure. First find out _where_ all that memory is used. A FIFO can be easily implemented using `Queue` or `Deque` interfaces (with several implementations already provided by the JDK)

Comment: `java.util.ArrayList` is about as memory efficient as possible. A linked list is definitely less memory-efficient. However, if you need to do FIFO processing, an `ArrayDeque` or an `ArrayBlockingQueue` might be better suited.

Comment: Thanks @knittl we know it is a memory issue, but cannot find out exactly where the issue is. one observation is, after the file has been processed say at 9:00 the memory comes down to its previous state before file processing begins but weirdly the memory then onwards gradually increases. we are not sure whats happening and how to find them. All looks good in tools like visualVM

Comment: @MarkRotteveel how efficient is ArrayDeque compared with ArrayList. right now I have used trimToSize for arrayList and clearing the data(changing to null) after 500 objects are processed. Do you think this would solve the issue in long run?

Comment: An ArrayDeque does not shrink again, as compared to e.g. a `LinkedList` (which has higher overhead for each node in the list). It is almost impossible to say where your leake is without seeing a [mre]. My suggestion: take a heap dump, then inspect your objects in the dump.

Comment: You can't trim an `ArrayDeque`, but if that is really your concern, then use an `ArrayBlockingQueue` so you have a maximum size. That way the producer is blocked if the consumers cannot keep up and the queue is full.

Comment: I will try taking heap dump and also see how well we can change to ArrayBlockingQueue as @MarkRotteveel suggested

Answer (score 0):

As @knittl suggested I took a heapdump and looks like Apache camel is causing this memory issue. We are pulling files from SFTP daily and decrypt them before going through data processing and inserting into DB. It looks like Apache camel is not freeing up the memory from its jsch buffer. Can someone suggest what we can do here?

Our camel is simple, sharing a sample here from("sftpUrl"+dynamic_fileName+".pgp").routeId("id").process(isDuplicateFile).unmarshal().pgp(somekey,user,pwd).unmarshal().string().process(writeToDBProcessor).log("Done");